# Crashed SDL_Mixer once; now all programs that use SDL_Mixer crash on initialization

Tags: c++, audio, crash, sdl, sdl-mixer

I was going through [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson11/index.php) on audio using SDL_mixer and everything went just fine.

After that I decided to experiment, play, and learn through exploration, so I made a program that was very similar, had two sound channels, and let me play some video game music, and push buttons to play game sound effects.

I then started having fun and button-mashing just to be silly and test the program. I started button mashing multiple buttons *really quickly* and then after doing that for probably 5 or so seconds the program closed unexpectedly.

Since that date 2 or so months ago, I have been unable to run -anything- on my computer that uses SDL_mixer. I've tried creating new projects with SDL_mixer, I've re-downloaded all of SDL and SDL_mixer, and even asked [this question on the sdl forums](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=8647).

I'm at the point where I'm going to reformat my entire computer to get it working again, which is -NOT- ok. An extension library should never force someone to reformat, especially when this is a problem that could potentially be passed onto end users who download and use the program later.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit; Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional; C++; and SDL 1.x

Also, if anyone knows what is wrong, how can I fix this, prevent it from happening again, and safely use sound so that I wouldn't cause problems on a user's computer?

The line I used to initialize the mixer is below:

```
//Initialize SDL_mixer 
if( Mix_OpenAudio( 22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096 ) == -1 ) 
{ 
    return false; 
}
```

The lines spat out by the debugger after I launch the program and it immediately closes:

```
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\SDL_Tutorial11.exe'. Symbols loaded. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\SDL.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\SDL_image.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\SDL_ttf.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libfreetype-6.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\zlib1.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\SDL_mixer.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110.dll'. Symbols loaded. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll'. Symbols loaded. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dsound.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll' 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MMDevAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AudioSes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libmikmod-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wdmaud.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\midimap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 
The thread 0x5b8 has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0x1d2c has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libpng15-15.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libvorbisfile-3.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libvorbis-0.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
'SDL_Tutorial11.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rayne\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\SDL_Tutorial11\Debug\libogg-0.dll'. Module was built without symbols. 
The thread 0x1a1c has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0x1fbc has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0x3f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0x584 has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0xa98 has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread 0x182c has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1d1c has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1278 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1d28 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1ca0 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1844 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x1340 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x6e8 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The thread 0x2008 has exited with code 1 (0x1). 
The program '[4852] SDL_Tutorial11.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

P.S. Is there an easier way to denote large sections of code without having to manually copy-past 4 spaces in front of every line? That took a while ._.;

Comment: Regarding indenting the code snippets, in the toolbar of the edit box there is a button looking like two braces `{}`, select the text you want to indent and press that button.

Comment: Thank you so much!~ I'm sure it'll be a complete life saver!~

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on line 195 (`bool quit = false;`, the first non-comment line of `main()`) does it get hit?

Comment: Yes!~ It does. And oh my gosh -THANKYOU- SO MUCH!!!!~

Because I was able to place a breakpoint there, I was able to successfully debug my program AND IT WORKED!!!~ Thank you SO much!!!~

Until now I hadn't been able to get any breakpoints to work, the program would exit before it would break for debugging but that ONE spot worked and let me debug and fix the problem.

What I -DON'T- get however, is that OTHER programs using SDL_mixer that HAD been working, also were crashing and having the same problem.

Comment: What ended up being the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to genpfault's advice I was able to discover a way to fix this.

It turns out that the solution was that when the program was crashing from over-loaded sound channels, that because the sounds had to be activated by key-presses, the queued up key presses were getting appended **into the program's source code** because Visual Studio automatically grabbed 'window focus' after the crash and 'caught' the excess characters.

The characters just happened to be appended to a string-literal of one of the first error-checking lines for the SDL_mixer functions in the very beginning of the program, so it wasn't throwing syntax errors for the compiler; the error check line was just saying "nope, the loaded file doesn't match this string exactly, so therefore close the program", which caused the program to be exiting before my break-points could register and allow me to debug.

It's an absolute relief to *finally* have this resolved.

Thank you genpffault and stack-overflow!~

Comment: Ahahah!~ I only caught it because of your advice though. I had placed break points BEFORE that point, and AFTER that point, but never -at- that point before, and that one point did work. I didn't have the knowledge or expertise yet to realize that since I'm still new, but thanks to your advice I've learned a valuable lesson. So thanks :D